# How to display disk password prompt on all screens?

Tags: 16.04, boot, display, plymouth

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my laptop with an encrypted root partition.

Most of the time I use my laptop docked and closed, with 2 external monitors connected.

**When I cold boot or reboot Ubuntu, the disk unlock prompt appears on closed laptop's screen.** I have to blindly enter my password, then booting proceeds.

However, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> on plymouth's password prompt, Ubuntu will reboot and nicely display password prompt on all screens at their native resolutions.

How can I configure Ubuntu/plymouth to always do that?

TL;DR:

### I want the encrypted disk password prompt to always appear on all displays.

---

Details that probably don't matter:

- My setup doesn't use LVM
- `/home` is also encrypted and unlocked with a keyfile stored in `/`
- `/boot` is on separate, unencrypted partition
- Originally no partitions were encrypted, I have set it up later
- I'm using UEFI boot, this is my `grub.cfg` on ESP:

  ```
  search.fs_uuid ebfd16b2-f259-456f-ba8d-dd126e79a701 root hd0,gpt5 
  set prefix=($root)'/grub'
  configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a week or so (end of May 2018) Plymouth password prompt displays on all screens as expected. So for now, the solution is to **install updates**. I don't know which update specifically fixed this.